# How do I recolor part of this shape in illustrator to create a 2-color svg?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I created shapes (icons) in photoshop and copied / pasted into illustrator in order to save as SVG, but I need to make one half of each icon (each 2-component icons) a different color.

[image]

I'm pretty new to Illustrator, so this may be trivial but I have no idea how to do it. Perhaps I have to create multiple layers for different shapes to have different colors, but I also have some of the shapes masking others, so I'm not sure how that works out.

Comment: Could you provide the img of icons that you created? If your icon has other independent parts which you can select and change the color, it's possible.

Comment: @twinklingstar I've added a screen shot of an example.

Comment: You want to change the color of the bottom part of the circle (white)?

Comment: @twinklingstar It's a simple icon of a person and I just want to make the lower red part (shoulders) a darker red. The parts that are not colored shouldn't be colored or anything, just the two red shapes should be 2 different colors. Perhaps there's a way to get rid of the overlay and join all paths into 2 simple shapes?

Comment: @JonathanTodd Err just click on the lower red shape and change color of the fill. THis s a bit different form your description above but yes ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Select > Select All`
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- Click the white shapes and delete them
- Click the bottom shape and change the color

[image]

Note I'm using the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) for a reason here. You should do the same.

Comment: This is why you have 80K rep.

Comment: Taking the time to make a gif? +1

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I got you right, you just need to draw the rectangle (it seems you have it already) to divide your circle into (shoulder and bottom part which you'll remove later), select to objects circle and rectangle go pathfinders / devide

2. remove the rect and the bottom part
3. select it and change the color.
4. save as / svg